# Having an issue while opening external BIRT link in Vaadin14

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, rapidclipse

### I am trying to take input from the below screen and open Birt Report directly into PDF. (I am using Vaadin 14)

**Problem:**
*My Anchor/Button is not opening any link on the first click every time this UI gets loaded. But After clicking once from the second click onward, it is working fine. Any Idea what can be the issue and what mistake I've made?*

[image]

**Below are my global Variables:**

```
final Button                    printButton                     =
    new Button("Print Report", VaadinIcon.PRINT.create());
String                          url                             = null;
final Anchor                    anchorReport                    = new Anchor();
```

**My Consutructor:**

```
public AssignmentCompletedAllRPTView()
{
    super();
    this.initUI();
    this.radioButtonGroup.setItems("Yes", "No");
    this.printButton.addClickListener(new ComponentEventListener<ClickEvent<Button>>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onComponentEvent(final ClickEvent<Button> event)
        {
            AssignmentCompletedAllRPTView.this.printButton();
        }
    });
    this.ConfigureReportButton();
}
```

**ConfigureReportButton():**

```
private void ConfigureReportButton()
{
    this.anchorReport.setTarget("_blank");
    this.anchorReport.add(this.printButton);
    this.buttonHorizontalLayout.add(this.anchorReport);
}
```

**printButton():**

```
private void printButton()
{
        final String reportURL = //--URL
        this.anchorReport.setHref(reportURL);
}
```

Comment: Can you minimize your code sample to contain only the lines required to reproduce the issue? Now there's a large amount of code that I assume is unrelated to the issue at hand, like all of the logging.

Comment: I don't know actually where it is having an issue on the first click. I am so sorry but will short out the printButton() method. Removing all the logs. I did it.

Comment: Are those Notifications required to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I removed all the unnecessary code. I hope someone will reply to me, what did I do wrong in the coding and not in posting :( .

Comment: I have also noticed: It is always taking the previous Value. For example, In the initial click, it doesn't set anything and then changes the date it picks the previous values and not the current.

Comment: Cleaning up the code example was helpful. It's somewhat confusing that you have both a component named `printButton` and a method `printButton`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two components here: a `Button` and an `Anchor`. Your `Button` is placed inside the `Anchor` in `ConfigureReportButton`. Your `Button` also gets a click listener in the constructor.

When you first click the button inside the anchor, the anchor has no `href`, so it does nothing. It also it executes the method `printButton`, which updates the `href` of the anchor. When you next click the button inside the anchor, the anchor has a `href` set, so it loads the file. It also executes the click listener of the button again, so the `href` gets updated.

To fix the issue, execute `printButton()` at the end of the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by not using Anchor but by using executeJavaScript (although it is depricated but working fine):

```
UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJavaScript("window.open(\"" + reportURL + "\", \"_blank\");");
```